# How to show page preview of url entered like facebook wall?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, web

I that small description of the page should appear when user enters the url.

I have textbox where user enters url. I want when url is entered small textarea and div should appear which gives the preview of that url page content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is jQuery library using PHP with curl doing just that:

https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Facebook-Link-Preview

Answer (score 1):

Facebook takes the image from the this element in your header:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://yoursite.com/thumbImage.jpg" >
```

You can also use the specific meta tag for facebook:

```
<meta property='og:image' content='http://yoursite.com/thumbImage.jpg'/>
```

Documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/property-types/#image).

If none of them exist, then it it will take the first image on your site.

Comment: but it will show only text, what about text content ?

Comment: It will show an image. Not any text. Facebook doesn't show an screenshot of the site but just an image depending on the elements i talked about.

Comment: ok, mark has given nice answer.

Comment: Thanks for your effort!